# how do I test my ASP.NET website being hosted on shared server for lot of visitors a day?

Tags: asp.net, testing, web, traffic, capacity

I have property related website, going to be hosted on shared server. I want to test my site for large number of visitors.

Roughly I just want to get idea about response time by going thru each page while there are lot of concorrent page views
Is there any tool available that can simulate this

User need to login before they can do most of activities on site but Search feature is available to anyone and as usual it's going to be heavily used. I just want to make sure it's as smooth as it should be.

Any suggestions are welcome.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use wcat 6.3 tool from Microsoft. There are plenty of questions regarding using it here on so in case you need help.

You can download it here: http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1466

That is the x86 version, but there is also a link to the x64 version if that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called "Load testing". There are web sites that provide such services, some of them provide free testing.

Just Google for "free load testing" or "load testing". Find a service you want and it will generate required load on your web site and provide you with information you need.

Comment: thanks for reply, any particular that you have used and prefer i mean something which is quite easy I don't want to go for any complex solution I have very small team and low budget